# Lost assassins creed save progress by reinstalling windows

Tags: data-recovery, file-recovery

Lost assassins creed save progress by reinstalling Windows system.

Any idea how to recover it ?

Comment: If it dosen't have a cloud based backup system of some sort, and you didn't back it up, you're kind of out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

dit you format your drive prior to reinstalling??
or did you ''recover''??
if you format, you are f#$%ed lol  you can tried to call a special recovery business that will charge you few hundred bucks to ''tried to recover it...
if you installed it via steam, maybe you have a cloud save.

if you have a folder named windows old or something like it on your hard drive you might want to look in it

open user/(yourusername)  then type/appdata  it should look like  C:\Users\\AppData\    then open roaming, then try to find your file

if you dont have a window old
  open file explorer type %appdata%   open roaming then try to find your file.
if you still dont find it.   i'm sorry I can't help, I dont think of anything else.